# IPv4 configuration within a VM

Tags: 12.04, networking, server, virtualization, ip

I installed Ubuntu server 12.04 in a virtual machine. When I typed ifconfig, my network displayed a IPV6 IP address. How do I configure my 12.04 server to use IP v4?

Answer (score 0):

## ifconfig eth0

## ip -4 address show eth0

Then type the following to display IPV4

## netstat -nr -4